# Image on canvas looks different from image in html <img> tag

Tags: javascript, html, image, canvas, blurry

I am trying to use the HTML canvas to crop an image. But even before cropping the image, the image looks blurry when I rendered it on the canvas. I then rendered the same image using HTML  tag, and the image wasn't blurry. I used a width and height of 300px for both the canvas and the img  tag. I can't seem to be able to find out why the image looks blurry in the canvas.

```
const img = document.querySelector(".my-image");
const canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, img.naturalWidth, img.naturalHeight, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
```

The image rendered on the image tag looks like this:
[Image rendered with  tag](https://i.stack.imgur.com/COiVj.png)

And the image rendered on the canvas looks like this:
[Image rendered on canvas](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BmBq2.png)

Comment: You are scaling the image. You should set the canvas size to match the image size. Eg `canvas.width = img.naturalWidth;`  before `ctx.drawImage`  do same with height.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I look at the two images you share, the two images seem to be 600x600px.

- In the first case, with the `img` tag, the image appears to be displayed at 600x600px.
- In the second case, with the `canvas` method, you crop the image at 300x300px, but your page displays the result by stretching it at 600x600pxwhich seems to give this blurred effect.

[Information about the image sizes given by the broswer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ILqnX.png)